# why cannot I modify list?

Tags: html, css

I cannot modify the list which I mark by a comment in the code, and also cannot change background color of the id topicmenu which is supposed to be used to manipulate the list. Can anybody tell what is wrong with my code?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BBC News - HIEP</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin:0;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        .fixwidth{
            width: 1020px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding:0;
        }

        .break{
            clear: both;
        }

        #container{

        }

        #topbar{
            background-color:#7A0000;
            width:100%;
            height:40px;
            color: white;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        #logodiv{
            margin:0;
            float:left;
            border-right: 1px solid #990000;
            padding: 0 160px 0 0;
        }

        #logodiv img{
            position: relative;
            top:3px;
            margin:0;
            padding:0 10px 1px 0;
            border-right: 1px solid #990000;
        }

        #topmenudiv ul{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        #topmenudiv li{
            float: left;
            padding:10px 11px 13px 11px;
            margin:0;
            list-style: none;
            border-right: 1px solid #990000;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:0.8em;
        }

        #searchdiv{
            float: left;
            padding:7px 11px 5px 11px;
        }

        #searchdiv input{
            height: 18px;
            width: 185px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#525252;
            font-size:0.8em;
            background-image:url("image/magnify.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right center;
        }

        #headerbar{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background-color:#990000;
            width:100%;
            height:130px;
            color: white;
        }

        #headerbar p{
            margin:0;
        }

        #newsheader{
            float:left;
            font-size: 3em;
            padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        }

        #us{
            font-size:0.5em;
        }

        #rss{
            margin: 35px 10px 0 0;
            float:right;
            font-size:0.9em;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

        #rss img{
            height:16px;
        {

        #topicmenu{ /* the class that is used to manipulate the list*/
        }

        #topicmenu ul{
            background-color:#3E0C0D;
        }

        #topicmenu li{
            list-style: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id ="container">
        <div id = "topbar">
            <div class ="fixwidth">
                <div id="logodiv">
                    <a href="http://www.bbc.com/news/" target = _blank><img src="image/bbclogo.jpg" /></a>
                </div>
                <div id= "topmenudiv">
                    <ul>
                        <li>News</li>
                        <li>Sport</li>
                        <li>Weather</li>
                        <li>Earth</li>
                        <li>Future</li>
                        <li>Shop</li>
                        <li>TV</li>
                        <li>Radio</li>
                        <li>More...</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="searchdiv">
                    <input type = "text" placeholder ="Search"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class ="break"></div>

        <div id="headerbar">
            <div class ="fixwidth">
                <p id ="newsheader" >NEWS <span id="us">US</span></p>
                <div id = "rss">
                    RSS <img src = "image/rss.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class ="break"></div>
                <div id ="topicmenu"> <!-- the list I get trouble from-->
                    <ul>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>World</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<img src="image/bbclogo.jpg" />` should be `<img src="image/bbclogo.jpg" alt="BBC News" />`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H37.html

Comment: `<html>` should be something like `<html lang="en">`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H57.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm maybe because:

```
#rss img{
    height:16px;
{
```

^ should be `}`

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit confusing, you cant change the background-color of the class "topicmenu" because there is no class "topicmenu" in your html. But there is an id topicmenu...

Also the main reason why you cant style it properly because you did not have any closing tag in your #rss img {... , you should have ther #rss img {....}

here's a working fiddle for your problem

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/owjwm8uw/>
```

Another thing, try making your code as clean as possible... avoid having space between your id/class and the equal sign, something like:

yourid ="blabla", it should be yourid="blabla"

cheers mate,
Advance Merry Christmas!